# Optimal data science workflow for storing Jupyter files in GitHub but running and editing in Docker

Tags: git, docker, github, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I am writing an model analysis notebook which will be run automatically upon model training to store various graphs and metrics. The model is trained and hosted using a Docker container, so I am running the notebook inside a local instance of the Docker container and port forwarding that to my browser. It would be difficult to replicate the Docker file system setup outside the Docker container so running the Jupyter notebook anywhere outside the Docker container appears challenging.

However, this means I am editing the Jupyter notebook in the Docker container instead of the git-tracked notebook file in my local computer. If I edit the Docker Jupyter, but fail to download it to my local computer and replace the outdated local version, then upon the next Docker build call using the local files, all my changes will be overwritten. Thus far, this has not occurred, but either way this workflow seems really sub-optimal. Does anyone know a better way to do this sort of development?

If I am doing a lot of things wrong to end up in this situation, I would like to hear about that as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So I was indeed doing things quite wrong. My source files were being copied into the container as I push the image onto AWS for usage. However, for development, I can simply replace the source files with the actual files on my local computer by mounting the source directory to the directory my source files were originally copied to. This way, when I edit the Jupyter notebook, it is the actual Jupyter notebook I am editing rather than a copy of it.